# Kinda confused about the first homomorphism theorem of groups

Tags: group-theory

For a group $G$, let $f$ be a homomorphism on $G$. By the theorem, we have $G \simeq ker(f) \times im(f)$.

But by mapping $\mathbb{F}_4$ into $\mathbb{F}_2$, didn't we get:$$\mathbb{F}_4\simeq\mathbb{F}_2\times\mathbb{F}_2?$$

What's wrong? Is it because $G \simeq ker(f) \times im(f)$ cannot be derived from $G /ker(f)\simeq im(f)$ ?

I know it's clearly wrong but I just can't find the mistake..

Comment: @JohnHughes Even a semidirect product won't suffice, as the sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z}/4 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$ isn't split; or alternatively, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ has only the trivial automorphism, so the only semidirect product one may construct with it as the normal subgroup is the direct product.

Comment: Thanks, Alex...I knew as I wrote it that I had doubts, but couldn't come up wth that example quickly, and thought "maybe...". So I'll delete that comment and replace it with this: You've correctly identified the problem: the theorem says the thing just before "?", while your conversion to a product is mistaken. (I *thought* the correct claim was that it's a semidirect product, but even that's too strong, as Alex shows above).

Answer (score 1):

The first isomorphism theorem says $G/ker(f) \sim im(f)$. It is tempting to conclude that $G \sim ker(f) \times im(f)$ but as your example shows this cannot be true.

This is exactly why the FIT is stated in the given form and NOT stated as $G \sim ker(f) \times im(f)$.